# Twilio Dynamic Text-To-Speech Conversation

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I'm new to using the Twilio API and I essentially want someone to be able to send text and have it be read out in the phone call, but then keep the line open so that more text can be sent at a later time.

It seems like I should be using the Programmable Voice API along with TwilML, but the problem I am having is that once the TwilML instructions are completed the call ends. Is there anyway I can stop this from happening and have the call wait for a Rest API update to be sent to the phone call to have it say new text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a few ways you could deal with this, but I believe the best would be to use [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue). Once your TwiML is played out, you can `<Enqueue>` the call and then provide a [`waitUrl`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue#attributes-waitUrl) that points to an endpoint that returns more TwiML to play to the user while they wait. This will automatically loop while the user remains in the queue. You could use this to simply [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) indefinitely or [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) background music. Then, once you have more text to read to the user you can [redirect the call by updating it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. I was able to <Enqueue> the call to a silent wait TwiML using <Pause>. I was then able to update the once I had more text. Thanks!